# Remove 'Your Name' field from comments display

Tags: 7, entities, theming, comments

I want to hide/remove the "Your Name" field from the comments on a Drupal 7 site.

I am using the bamboo theme and Drupal 7.

I have seen a few threads for the but most are about removing the subject line, or are about Drupal 6 etc. I have tried a few different methods I have seen, but have not succeeded in getting this to work on Drupal 7 as of yet. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The name input is not a required field,  so the easiest thing would be to hide it using CSS.

Try the following:

```
.comment-wrapper .form-item-name { display: none; }
```

You could also use hook_form_alter().  Check for the $form_id  for the comment form,  then set:
`$form['FIELD NAME GOES HERE']['#access'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Any particular place to place the CSS option, or just in the main css file for the theme?

Comment: generally speaking, place it at the bottom of your theme's stylesheet.

Comment: Unfortunately the first option doesn't seem to be working. Will try the second once I can work out the name of the field. For clarifiction what I'm trying to do here though, I want to remove the field from both the form and from display. I've used other techniques to get the field to disapear from the form, but then the username still shows up when the comment is submitted.

Comment: I would highly recommend learning to use the HTML/CSS inspector in your favourite web browser.

Hiding it with CSS should work, you just have to make sure the selectors are correct.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is just an area I will have to learn the skills at. I was hoping there'd a be a solution involving modules and/or settings, as opposed to actually needing to get code proficient. Seems like an odd thing not to have a  module/option for.

Comment: Turn off css aggregation while you work on your css, or you wont see any effect taking place ever.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, I have had a look at the CSS route, and this did work. So thank you very much for your help. Took me a bit of trial and error wth Chrome Developer Tools but got there.
Unfortunately, however it doesn't qyite server the purpose I want it for, which is a bit of a pain, but that's my bad for poor explanation. I wanted to give users the change to make anonymous comments (not security grade, and was aware theyd still appear in the backend) but just to remove from each other. However the username still shows up in Developer window, so no win. My bad though, so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this that worked for me.

If you're theme has a comment.tpl.php file, if you search this file somehwere there will be a `<?php print $author; ?>` piece of script. Removing this worked for me. It's a bit of a hack, but stops the username still appearing in the developer tools, which means you can have authenticated users post anonymously.

Comment: It isn't a hack if you copy the file into your themes folder - this is a perfectly good way to override a template :-)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved it based on jdu's method. Insert following code into your themes template.php file inside your hook_form_alter() function:

```
if ($form_id == "comment_node_article_form") {
  $form['author']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

This needs to be done for all node types with comments enabled.

IMO this method is better than using css, since css only hides it from display, not from the rendered html.